# Column expressions and data sources without names or aliases cannot be formatted as JSON text using FOR JSON clause

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, xml

I have this query:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        US.Description,
        US.Title Summary,
        ISNULL(US.MyWizardUserStoryId,'')UserStoryID,
        A.RequirementId,ISNULL(US.ProjectId,'')ProjectId,
    --(case when A.AnalysisOutcome='Found' then 'Ambiguous' else 'Non Ambiguous' end) 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='' THEN 'Analysis Pending'  
         WHEN ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Found' THEN 'Ambiguities found'
         WHEN ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Not Found' THEN 'No Ambiguities'         
         WHEN ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Submitted' THEN 'Submitted'      
         WHEN ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Rejected' THEN 'Rejected'        
         WHEN (ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Internal Processing Failure'

         OR ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Requirement Not Parsable')
          THEN 'Analysis failure' 
    END as AnalysisOutcome,
    US.AssignedTo,
    ISNULL(AD.RequirementAnalysisId,'')RequirementAnalysisId,
    AD.VagueWord,
    AD.ContentText,
    AD.Explanation,
    AD.Suggestion,
    AD.SuggestionList,
    US.Title Summary2,
    AD.VaguePhrase,
    AD.VagueTypeText
    ,AD.VagueWord VagueWord2
    ,US.ModifiedOn
 FROM (RequirementAnalysis A 
 RIGHT JOIN UserStory US ON
 A.RequirementId=US.MyWizardUserStoryId)
 left JOIN
              AmbiguityAnalysisResult AD ON
              A.RequirementAnalysisId=AD.RequirementAnalysisId
              AND
              A.RequirementAnalysisId=(SELECT MAX(RequirementAnalysisId) FROM RequirementAnalysis WHERE  RequirementId=A.RequirementId
                                AND ProjectId=A.ProjectId)
)
SELECT  UserStoryId, 
        [Description], 
        Summary, 
        UserStoryID,
        ProjectId,
        AnalysisOutcome,
        AssignedTo,
        RequirementAnalysisId,
        RequirementId,
        (SELECT distinct VagueWord
        FROM cte
        WHERE UserStoryId = c.UserStoryId
        FOR XML PATH('VagueWordsArray'),TYPE)
        ,
        (SELECT ContentText,Explanation,Suggestion,     
        SuggestionList,     
        Summary,VaguePhrase,VagueTypeText,VagueWord
        FROM cte
        WHERE UserStoryId = c.UserStoryId
        FOR XML PATH('SuggestionData'),TYPE)
FROM cte c
WHERE UserStoryId in (141204,1400235)
GROUP BY  UserStoryId, 
        [Description], 
        Summary, 
        UserStoryID,
        ProjectId,
        AnalysisOutcome,
        AssignedTo,
        RequirementAnalysisId,
        RequirementId
FOR XML PATH('StoryData'),ROOT('xml'),TYPE
```

This query is returning this XML:

```
<xml>
  <StoryData>
    <UserStoryId>141204</UserStoryId>
    <Description>Customer can see the applicable discount on the quote and change in premium.</Description>
    <Summary>Customer can see the applicable discount on the quote and change in premium.</Summary>
    <UserStoryID>141204</UserStoryID>
    <ProjectId>23040</ProjectId>
    <AnalysisOutcome>Ambiguities found</AnalysisOutcome>
    <AssignedTo>ankit.k.arora</AssignedTo>
    <RequirementAnalysisId>5901</RequirementAnalysisId>
    <RequirementId>141204</RequirementId>
    <VagueWordsArray>
      <VagueWord>and</VagueWord>
    </VagueWordsArray>
    <VagueWordsArray>
      <VagueWord>applicable</VagueWord>
    </VagueWordsArray>
    <SuggestionData>
      <ContentText>Customer can see the applicable discount on the quote and change in premium.</ContentText>
      <Explanation>Suggests that you are combining requirements. Requirements that contain conjunctions/disjunctions (AND/OR) are dangerous and can lead to downstream problems in defining scope of the requirement.</Explanation>
      <Suggestion>Keep each requirement in a single sentence.</Suggestion>
      <Summary>Customer can see the applicable discount on the quote and change in premium.</Summary>
      <VagueTypeText>Not Standard</VagueTypeText>
      <VagueWord>and</VagueWord>
    </SuggestionData>
    <SuggestionData>
      <ContentText>Customer can see the applicable discount on the quote and change in premium.</ContentText>
      <Explanation>Can be interpreted in different ways by different people.</Explanation>
      <Suggestion>Include the precise definition in the glossary.</Suggestion>
      <Summary>Customer can see the applicable discount on the quote and change in premium.</Summary>
      <VaguePhrase>applicable discount</VaguePhrase>
      <VagueTypeText>Not Defined</VagueTypeText>
      <VagueWord>applicable</VagueWord>
    </SuggestionData>
  </StoryData>
  <StoryData>
    <UserStoryId>1400235</UserStoryId>
    <Description>story 1</Description>
    <Summary>undefined</Summary>
    <UserStoryID>1400235</UserStoryID>
    <ProjectId>23040</ProjectId>
    <AnalysisOutcome>Rejected</AnalysisOutcome>
    <AssignedTo>anmol.aggarwal@accenture.com</AssignedTo>
    <RequirementAnalysisId>5958</RequirementAnalysisId>
    <RequirementId>1400235</RequirementId>
    <VagueWordsArray>
      <VagueWord>and</VagueWord>
    </VagueWordsArray>
    <VagueWordsArray>
      <VagueWord>or</VagueWord>
    </VagueWordsArray>
    <VagueWordsArray>
      <VagueWord>should</VagueWord>
    </VagueWordsArray>
    <SuggestionData>
      <ContentText>Story should or and not fail</ContentText>
      <Explanation>Suggests that you are combining requirements. Requirements that contain conjunctions/disjunctions (AND/OR) are dangerous and can lead to downstream problems in defining scope of the requirement.</Explanation>
      <Suggestion>Keep each requirement in a single sentence.</Suggestion>
      <SuggestionList />
      <Summary>undefined</Summary>
      <VagueTypeText>Not Standard</VagueTypeText>
      <VagueWord>and</VagueWord>
    </SuggestionData>
    <SuggestionData>
      <ContentText>Story should or and not fail</ContentText>
      <Explanation>Suggests that you are combining requirements. Requirements that contain conjunctions/disjunctions (AND/OR) are dangerous and can lead to downstream problems in defining scope of the requirement.</Explanation>
      <Suggestion>Keep each requirement in a single sentence.</Suggestion>
      <SuggestionList />
      <Summary>undefined</Summary>
      <VagueTypeText>Not Standard</VagueTypeText>
      <VagueWord>or</VagueWord>
    </SuggestionData>
    <SuggestionData>
      <ContentText>Story should or and not fail</ContentText>
      <Explanation>Is often ambiguous, or inappropriate. Some readers will interpret these as optional or advisory, others as required.</Explanation>
      <Suggestion>Use 'shall/must/will' for requirements,</Suggestion>
      <SuggestionList>shall,must,will</SuggestionList>
      <Summary>undefined</Summary>
      <VagueTypeText>Not Standard</VagueTypeText>
      <VagueWord>should</VagueWord>
    </SuggestionData>
  </StoryData>
</xml>
```

I am trying to convert same into a `FOR JSON` query, but I get this error :

> Msg 13605, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column expressions and data sources without names or aliases cannot be formatted as JSON text using FOR JSON clause. Add alias to the unnamed column or table.

I have tried below query for Json:

```
;WITH cte AS(
SELECT 
US.Description
,US.Title Summary
,ISNULL(US.MyWizardUserStoryId,'')UserStoryID
,A.RequirementId,ISNULL(US.ProjectId,'')ProjectId,
    --(case when A.AnalysisOutcome='Found' then 'Ambiguous' else 'Non Ambiguous' end) 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='' THEN 'Analysis Pending'  
         WHEN ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Found' THEN 'Ambiguities found'
         WHEN ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Not Found' THEN 'No Ambiguities'         
         WHEN ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Submitted' THEN 'Submitted'      
         WHEN ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Rejected' THEN 'Rejected'        
         WHEN (ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Internal Processing Failure'

         OR ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Requirement Not Parsable')
          THEN 'Analysis failure' 
    END as AnalysisOutcome,
    US.AssignedTo,
    ISNULL(AD.RequirementAnalysisId,'')RequirementAnalysisId,
    AD.VagueWord,
    AD.ContentText,
    AD.Explanation,
    AD.Suggestion,
    AD.SuggestionList,

    AD.VaguePhrase,
    AD.VagueTypeText

    ,US.ModifiedOn


 FROM (RequirementAnalysis A 
 RIGHT JOIN UserStory US ON
 A.RequirementId=US.MyWizardUserStoryId)
 left JOIN
              AmbiguityAnalysisResult AD ON
              A.RequirementAnalysisId=AD.RequirementAnalysisId
              AND
              A.RequirementAnalysisId=(SELECT MAX(RequirementAnalysisId) FROM RequirementAnalysis WHERE  RequirementId=A.RequirementId
                                AND ProjectId=A.ProjectId)
)    


SELECT  UserStoryId, 
        [Description], 
        Summary, 
        UserStoryID,
        ProjectId,
        AnalysisOutcome,
        AssignedTo,
        RequirementAnalysisId,
        RequirementId
        ,
        (SELECT distinct VagueWord
        FROM cte
        WHERE UserStoryId = c.UserStoryId
        FOR Json PATH,ROOT('VagueWordsArray'))
        ,
        (SELECT ContentText,Explanation,Suggestion,     
        SuggestionList,     
        Summary,VaguePhrase,VagueTypeText,VagueWord
        FROM cte
        WHERE UserStoryId = c.UserStoryId
        FOR Json PATH,ROOT('SuggestionData'))
FROM cte c
WHERE UserStoryId in (141204,1400235)
GROUP BY  UserStoryId, 
        [Description], 
        Summary, 
        UserStoryID,
        ProjectId,
        AnalysisOutcome,
        AssignedTo,
        RequirementAnalysisId,
        RequirementId
FOR Json PATH,ROOT('StoryData')
```

Comment: First of all, FOR JSON works only for MSSQL 2016 and above.
second, please verify that you have aliases to all of your displayed columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify to column aliases for all columns and in your query there is no defined aliases for subselects.

```
(SELECT distinct VagueWord
FROM cte
WHERE UserStoryId = c.UserStoryId
FOR Json PATH,ROOT('VagueWordsArray')) as VagueWordAlias
```

and

```
(SELECT 
ContentText,
Explanation,
Suggestion,     
SuggestionList,     
Summary,VaguePhrase,VagueTypeText,VagueWord
FROM cte
WHERE UserStoryId = c.UserStoryId
FOR Json PATH,ROOT('SuggestionData')) as SuggestionDataAlias
```

So complete query looks like;

```
;WITH cte AS(
SELECT 
US.Description
,US.Title Summary
,ISNULL(US.MyWizardUserStoryId,'')UserStoryID
,A.RequirementId,ISNULL(US.ProjectId,'')ProjectId,
    --(case when A.AnalysisOutcome='Found' then 'Ambiguous' else 'Non Ambiguous' end) 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='' THEN 'Analysis Pending'  
         WHEN ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Found' THEN 'Ambiguities found'
         WHEN ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Not Found' THEN 'No Ambiguities'         
         WHEN ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Submitted' THEN 'Submitted'      
         WHEN ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Rejected' THEN 'Rejected'        
         WHEN (ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Internal Processing Failure'

         OR ISNULL(A.AnalysisOutcome,'')='Requirement Not Parsable')
          THEN 'Analysis failure' 
    END as AnalysisOutcome,
    US.AssignedTo,
    ISNULL(AD.RequirementAnalysisId,'')RequirementAnalysisId,
    AD.VagueWord,
    AD.ContentText,
    AD.Explanation,
    AD.Suggestion,
    AD.SuggestionList,

    AD.VaguePhrase,
    AD.VagueTypeText

    ,US.ModifiedOn


 FROM (RequirementAnalysis A 
 RIGHT JOIN UserStory US ON
 A.RequirementId=US.MyWizardUserStoryId)
 left JOIN
              AmbiguityAnalysisResult AD ON
              A.RequirementAnalysisId=AD.RequirementAnalysisId
              AND
              A.RequirementAnalysisId=(SELECT MAX(RequirementAnalysisId) FROM RequirementAnalysis WHERE  RequirementId=A.RequirementId
                                AND ProjectId=A.ProjectId)
)    


SELECT  UserStoryId, 
        [Description], 
        Summary, 
        UserStoryID,
        ProjectId,
        AnalysisOutcome,
        AssignedTo,
        RequirementAnalysisId,
        RequirementId
        ,
        (SELECT distinct VagueWord
        FROM cte
        WHERE UserStoryId = c.UserStoryId
        FOR Json PATH,ROOT('VagueWordsArray')) as VagueWordAlias
        ,
        (SELECT 
        ContentText,
        Explanation,
        Suggestion,     
        SuggestionList,     
        Summary,VaguePhrase,VagueTypeText,VagueWord
        FROM cte
        WHERE UserStoryId = c.UserStoryId
        FOR Json PATH,ROOT('SuggestionData')) as SuggestionDataAlias
FROM cte c
WHERE UserStoryId in (141204,1400235)
GROUP BY  UserStoryId, 
        [Description], 
        Summary, 
        UserStoryID,
        ProjectId,
        AnalysisOutcome,
        AssignedTo,
        RequirementAnalysisId,
        RequirementId
FOR Json PATH,ROOT('StoryData')
```